# Why are my images moving from jQuery UI bounce effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I just want the *bounce* effect to be on the `mouseover` of the #bounce1,2,3... images on the homepage, but it seems to be forcing images to the next line.

What gives?

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: Need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to add this to your style sheet.

```
#fp_brands a .ui-effects-wrapper { 
float: left !important; 
width: 33% !important;
}
```

The ui-effect-wrapper div that jquery-ui uses in it's animations can sometimes mess up floated elements. This is because it's css rules include width: 100%; and float: none;

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same effect without JavaScript and jQuery, using only CSS3. Use `@keyframes` to define the key frames and then use it in `animation` property.
Here is the [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QxQud/1/) regarding to your example.
For more information about the `animation` property of CSS3 please check [this URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations).

Answer (score 0):

Using the element inspector, applying `float:left;` to each image made them animate as desired. I would apply it to the class `attachment-medium` if you don't use it anywhere else to save code

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this css and remove `width="33%"` from `img` tag?

```
.attachment-medium {
    position:relative;
    width:235px;
    height:100px;
}
```